# how to use prestashop with mongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, prestashop

I am starting to implement an e-commerce module with PHP. I analyzed and get prestashop is perfact for my requirement. I read almost all documentation of prestashop but I never find **mongoDB**. I decided to use database mongoDB. But I am not sure how to use it with prestashop.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't be possible because all classes and module use SQL queries;

I would be theoretically possible to build your own Db driver implementation, but then again you couldn't use it since it needs to process SQL.

Currently there are 3 Db driver type: PDO, mysqli and MySQL, the best one is selected based on server PHP version.

Comment: is there any references about it ?

Comment: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Best+Practices+of+the+Db+Class But this is just "how to use" and methods descriptions. I'm currently working on these Db classes, you can see them yourself if you download latest PrestaShop `classes/db/` - nothing too complicated there.